What is a high number of 'VM Exit's?
When using a virtual machine, one of the key performance parameters is 'VM exits'. I have a multicore VM under VM VirtualBox, indicating on average 30k VM exits per second, but I have nothing to compare this value to, whether high or completely reasonable.
How does one evaluate this parameter and its performance impact?

I don't know the answer, but as a sample point, I have just converted a CentOS 6 OpenVZ kernel physical host to a VM because of hardware failure, and I see about 1k VM exits/s, while idling. If you have any more insight, please update your Q or even answer it

Another sample point, I tried setting the graphics adapter to "none", attempting to make the VM headless, and that got grub stuck in a loop, unable to start the kernel. In this 'stuck; state, the VM exits meter was at 1.5M/s. This might be a "high" number, while the 1k/s might be 'normalish'

Still not answering the question, but I found a useful study of VM Exits, specifically concerned with minimizing the number of VM exits caused by periodic tick timers, ie, due to interaction with virtualized timer devices. It suggests that an idle kernel with periodic ticks would exit about 10 times/tick, and that modern kernels are tickless, ie, they exit less often - https://web.njit.edu/~dingxn/papers/paratick.pdf - this tells me that a tickless kernel should exit much less than 10k/s and a legacy kernel ticking at 1ms would exit about 10k/s

My numbers above are for a VM with 1 vCPU - I understand that timer tick processing, and hence VM exits, scales linearly with the number of allocated vCPU's

From VirtualBox
3.6. Details About Hardware Virtualization:

With Intel VT-x, there are two distinct modes of CPU operation: VMX
root mode and non-root mode.

In root mode, the CPU operates much like older generations of processors without VT-x support. There are four privilege levels,
called rings, and the same instruction set is supported, with the
addition of several virtualization specific instruction. Root mode is
what a host operating system without virtualization uses, and it is
also used by a hypervisor when virtualization is active.

In non-root mode, CPU operation is significantly different. There are still four privilege rings and the same instruction set, but a new
structure called VMCS (Virtual Machine Control Structure) now controls
the CPU operation and determines how certain instructions behave.
Non-root mode is where guest systems run.


Switching from root mode to non-root mode is called "VM entry", the
switch back is "VM exit". The VMCS includes a guest and host state
area which is saved/restored at VM entry and exit. Most importantly,
the VMCS controls which guest operations will cause VM exits.

This means that control is switched between guest and host. Most likely
this is because of the guest accessing host resources such as the disk.
VM products usually implement virtual cores as threads or processes
on the host, so switching between virtual cores involves switching
execution between host threads/processes. This will also require
host API, so more control switches.
Control switches are a relatively slow operation, but they are also
very dependent upon the hardware and the software in action.
Their performance cannot be compared except to an identical or similar
environment.
